# NetBeans Doesn't recognize project folders

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

NetBeans run programs and create project normally, but when I try to open an existing Project it doesn't recognize the project folder so when I click "Open Project" it doesn't open it.
it works fine using intellij IDE but I need To use NetBeans .
I tried using Import Project But the Same problem.
when I try to Import it it gives me an error :"C:\Users\ahmad\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\ch24" does not contain a regular Eclipse project."

I uninstalled NetBeans 12.4 before installing NetBeans 13 if this may help.

When I try to open project:
1)
[image: Trying to open project]
2)
[image]

I read on the internet I should change NetBeans.conf file Java home, but it was the right path already.
3) [image]

4. [image: Project]

I searched on the internet but found really old posts (9 years) and didn't work with me, such as changing java home path in netbeans conf. Using import Project.

Tried Moving the folder to NeatBeans Project folder but the same problem.

Comment: NetBeans only recognizes (standard) Maven or Gradle projects or its own Ant based project folders. If your folder is neither of those, then your only option is to create a new NetBeans (Ant based) project "with existing sources". Or convert it to a Maven project. The settings of JAVA_HOME have nothing to do with using/importing existing projects.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My peers Open the project using NeatBeans without issues

Comment: and who is to say, locally they haven't already done this?

Comment: The first question is: what kind of project do your peers use? Maybe you forgot to copy the POM (if it's a Maven project) or the `build.gradle` (if it's a Gradle project) or the NetBeans project folder that contains the build.xml (if it's a NetBeans Ant project)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah know I understand, I though netbeans is like intellij or eclipse but it appears that it is operate in different way. Thank you

Comment: IntelliJ and Eclipse both have their own project structure - just like NetBeans (with their Ant based projects). If you want something you can easily use across different IDEs, use Maven or Gradle.